# Turbogears 2 - validating forms to the same url

Tags: turbogears2

I have a controller for a contact page similar to the following:

```
@expose('project.templates.contacts')
def contact(self, **kw):
    return dict( form=contact_form )
```

Upon submission the form is validated using the following controller method:

```
@validate(form=contact_form, error_handler=contact)
@expose()
def processContact(self, **kw):
    # Do some processing on the contact form
    redirect('contact')
```

The is the setup advocated by many online tutorials (such as http://turbogears.org/2.0/docs/main/FormBasics.html).

My issue is the URL that is exposed when the contact form is submitted with bad data and @validate calls the error_handler method.

I.e.

1. "**http://domain/contact**" - the user goes to the contact page and fills in the form and click submit
2. "**http://domain/contact**" - if there are no errors in the form, the user is successfully redirected to the contact page.
3. "**http://domain/processContact**" - if there are errors in the form, the contact function is called but there is no redirection from the exposed processContact 'page' so the url remains the same.

I'm looking for a way (the correct way?) to prevent the user from having to see "**http://domain/processContact**". Ideally the user should only ever see "**http://domain/contact**".

Answer (score 0):

[this is not an answer, but more of a comment, but for reputation issues, I'm not allowed to add comments]
Your description of the problem seemed a bit vague to me. As far as I know, the user won't see "http://domain/processContact" as doesnt have any link in its expose. In other words, what I understand from your codes is that:
1- in case of error in the form, the user will be redirected to contact page where you access the entered inputs
2- in case of success, the user will be redirected to a new contact page

Id I'm mistaken, please clarify your problem a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Set as form action the *contact* page itself, add a **@validate** to it but don't provide the **error_handler**. If you omit it, instead of calling the error_handler the flow goes on and you just find your errors in **tmpl_context.form_errors**.

Then inside your controller you have to handle three cases:

1. tg.request.method is GET -> Render the form
2. tg.request.method is POST and tmpl_contet.form_errors is not empty -> Render the form
3. tg.request.method is POST and no tmpl_contet.form_errors -> process submit + redirect